# How can you configure node-gyp complied modules to use mutiple compile threads, like -j8?

Tags: node.js, compilation, node-gyp

I've noticed that all node modules that compile C code are running only a single threaded compile.

As it often happens that I end up retrying node module installations multiple times, it would be nice at least that the C compile would utilise all cores.

is there some way to pass the j flag to the C compiler for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node-gyp uses the `JOBS` environment variable, raising it will result in more processes compiling. Example: `JOBS=max node-gyp build`

Alternatively, you can pass the Make flags directly, if you run `export MAKEFLAGS=-j8` before running node-gyp.